# Error: Association with alias \"alias_name\" does not exist on \"-Source Model-\""

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, associations

I have tried using associations in sequelize to retrieve the information I need. However, when I use the include option, it throws an error saying that the relationship does not exist.

Here I have the code of my models

```
'use strict';
const {Model} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Employee extends Model {
  
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Employee.hasMany(models.EmployeePosition)
    }
  }

  Employee.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    bornDate:{
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: false
    },
    address:{ 
      type: DataTypes.STRING, 
      allowNull:false
    },
    hireDate:{
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,  
    },
    curp:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING(18),
      allowNull: false 
    },
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    salary: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    rfc:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING(13),
    },
    nss:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING(11)
    },
    telephone:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING(13),
      allowNull: false
    },
    driverLicense:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING()
    },
    ineFrontImageType:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    ineFrontImageName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    ineFrontImageData: {
      type: DataTypes.BLOB('long')
    },
    ineBackImageType:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    ineBackImageName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    ineBackImageData: {
      type: DataTypes.BLOB('long')
    },
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true,
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Employee',
    tableName: 'hrm_employees',
  },
  );  
  return Employee;
};
```

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class EmployeePosition extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      EmployeePosition.belongsTo(models.Employee)
      EmployeePosition.belongsTo(models.Position)
    }
  }
  EmployeePosition.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    employeeId:{
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references:{
        model: {
          tableName: 'hrm_employees'
        },
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    },
    positionId:{
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references:{
        model:{
          tableName: 'hrm_positions'
        },
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    },
  }, {
    modelName: 'EmployeePosition',
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true,
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'hrm_employees_positions',
  });
  return EmployeePosition;
};
```

Here is the code of my migrations

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */

module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('hrm_employees', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      born_date:{
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false
      },
      address:{ 
        type: Sequelize.STRING, 
        allowNull:false
      },
      hire_date:{
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,  
      },
      curp:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING(18),
        allowNull: false 
      },
      email: Sequelize.STRING,
      salary: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2),
        allowNull: false
      },
      rfc:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING(13),
      },
      nss:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING(11)
      },
      telephone:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING(13),
        allowNull: false
      },
      driver_license:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING()
      },
      ine_front_image_type:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      ine_front_image_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      ine_front_image_data: {
        type: Sequelize.BLOB('long')
      },
      ine_back_image_type:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      ine_back_image_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      ine_back_image_data: {
        type: Sequelize.BLOB('long')
      },
      created_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updated_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      deleted_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('hrm_employees');
  }
};
```

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('hrm_employees_positions', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      employee_id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName:'hrm_employees'
          },
          key: 'id'
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      position_id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'hrm_positions',
          },
          key: 'id'
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      created_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updated_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      deleted_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('hrm_employees_positions');
  }
};
```

And here is the code of my request

```
const {Sequelize, Op} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../database/database').sequelize;
const Employee = require('../../models/Employee')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes,Sequelize.Model);
const boom = require('@hapi/boom');

        const create = async (req, res, next) => {
                try{
                        const data = req.body
                        const {name,born_date, address, hire_date, curp, email, salary, rfc, nss, telephone} = data;
                        let nameLowerCase = name.toLowerCase();
                        const dateOfBirth = new Date(born_date);
                        const hireDate = new Date(hire_date);
                        const employee = await Employee.create({
                                name: nameLowerCase,
                                bornDate: dateOfBirth,
                                address,
                                hireDate,
                                curp,
                                email,
                                salary,
                                rfc,
                                nss,
                                telephone,
                        });
                        res.json({message: "created", data: employee});
                }catch(err){
                        next(err)
                }
        }
        

        const update = async (req, res, next) =>{
                try{
                        let employee = await Employee.findByPk(req.params.employee_id);

                        if(!employee)
                                throw boom.notFound('Empleado no encontrado');

                        employee= await employee.update(req.body)
                        res.json({message: "updated", data: employee});
                }catch(err){
                        next(err);
                }
        }
        
        const get = (async (req,res,  next) =>{
                try{
                        const employee = await Employee.findByPk(req.params.employee_id, {include: ['EmployeePosition']});
                        if(!employee)
                                throw boom.notFound('Empleado no encontrado');
                        res.json({message: "found", data: employee});
                }catch(err){
                        next(err);
                }
        })

        const index = (async (req, res, next) =>{
                try{
                        const{name, limit, page, telephone} = req.query;
                        const options = {
                                where:{}
                        }
                        options.include = ['EmployeePosition'];
                        if(limit && page){
                                options.limit = limit
                                options.page = page
                        }
                        if(name)
                                options.where.name = {
                                        [Op.like]:`%${name}%`
                                };
                        
                        if(telephone)
                                options.where.telephone = {
                                        [Op.like]:`%${telephone}%`
                                };
                        const employees = await Employee.findAll(options);
                        if(employees.length == 0)
                                throw boom.notFound('Empleados no encontrados');
                        res.json({message: "found", data: employees});                
                }catch(err){
                        next(err);  
                }
        })

        const destroy = (async (req, res, next) =>{
                try{
                        const employee = await Employee.findByPk(req.params.employee_id);
                        if(!employee)
                                throw boom.notFound('Empleado no encontrado');
                        await employee.destroy();
                        res.json({message: "deleted", data: employee});
                }catch(err){
                        next(err);
                }
        })

module.exports = {create, update,get,index, destroy};
```

**EDIT**
If I change the include objecto from
`options.include = ['EmployeePosition'];`

to

`options.include = {model: EmployeePosition,as: 'position'};`

Now I´m getting this error:

EmployeePosition is not associated to Employee!

However, I still can't seem to figure out how to make it work

I have tried using aliases, I have tried without using them, I have specified the name of the foreign key, but nothing works. I know the static method for association is executed when I start the server, but when I make the request in insomnia, it still shows the same error. I have changed the definition of the foreign key in both my model and migration, but nothing seems to work.
The employee migration is executed first, so it is the first table that is created.
Also, I tried the thing with plural nouns

Comment: Did you try `include: { model: EmployeePosition }`?

Comment: I did it, in the end I had to change how I built my models to get the relationships to work, since there had to be some progress. You could say that I didn't find the solution with that state of my code haha